# How to fight stiff neck after viral meningitis?

Tags: pain, neurology

My fiancee had suffered from viral meningitis last year. She was treated in hospital, spent there 10 days and was released to home. Since then she sometimes (once every 3-4 weeks) has episodes of head pain and neck pain/stiffness, which she usually helps with paracetamol + codeine (500mg + 30 mg does the trick).

When she catches a cold, these symptoms usually come back stronger.

My question is - is there any kind of treatment/therapy that would make these symptoms go away? Or will she be dependant on painkillers for the rest of her life?

Comment: This might depend on the virus that caused her meningitis. At least one virus has been found to persist and cause recurrences. This is something she needs to discuss with her doctor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Questions requesting personal medical advice are off topic here. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician. For more information, please see http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here